# slow perl performance, why and how to improve

Tags: perl

I ran NYTProf on a perl program, I am quite surprised to see the line with "unpack" takes lots of time: (the line got executed 14654 times and took 39.6ms). But the unpack() function itself is quite fast

```
    $delme1 = substr($data, 47,1)
    $_flags = unpack("C", $delme1);
    # spent  2.98ms making 14654 calls to main::CORE:unpack, avg 203ns/call
```

Any one knows why such a big overhead?

Thanks

**Update 1**
See the line with "unpack" call. It says it spent a total of 39.6ms.

[image]

Comment: i don't know what the numbers on the left mean, but it straight up told you the total was 2.98ms, and that each pass took 2.98 ms / 14654 calls = 203 ns/call

Comment: The column for 39.6ms has title "Time on line" according to NYTProf.  The column for 2.98ms is "Timein subs".  When I look at the total time spent in the routine that has the few lines, 39.6ms weighted heavily for the total time. Somehow, CPU spent lots of time on that line.

Comment: Coroberation: `perl -MBenchmark=timethis -e'timethis(-3, q{for (1..1000) { my $x = unpack("C", "X"); }});'` output `3283.39/s`, which is 1 unpack+assignment+loop every 304ns.

Comment: Is that the last line of a sub, loop or block?

Comment: There are other lines in the same routine too. The highlighted lines were not in any loop.

Comment: No. There are more lines following the highlighted line in the same routine.

Comment: No, they are not the last lines in the block (subroutine).  I thought I have given you the complete answer.

Comment: Then I don't know what that other number (39.6 ms) means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128668/discussion-between-packetie-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 2):

> the line got executed 14654 times and took 39.6ms

No, the line got executed 14654 times and took 2.98ms. Each execution took 203ns on average. Not exactly slow...

---

You could try using

```
$_flags = ord(substr($data, 47, 1));
```

or

```
$_flags = unpack('x47 C', $data);
```

---

There are surely better things to optimize. For example, you would benefit from having a single unpack rather than using multiple calls to substr and unpack.

Comment: You are right, I broken it up to see what is taking the time. It appears unpack() call.  Given that unpack() function itself is very efficient, I guess the overhead of invoking the call is very expensive.  Wonder if there is a way to speed it up.

Comment: There's no overhead to calling `unpack`. At all. Because there's no actual call, because it's not a subroutine; it's an operator just like `+`.